Aspects or respects? Which one expresses the sentence better?
In certain aspects, it is better to be average, like foot size
In certain respects,it is better to be average,like foot size

Much of the problem seems to stem from the fact that the example is so clearly contrived. Could you find a natural instance?
Either way, 'aspects' and 'respects' are no more comparable than 'apples' and 'oranges'…
An 'aspect' is loosely a characteristic of the subject.
A 'respect' is loosely the point of view of an observer (of the subject)
Then, which do think expresses the idea better?

In the cited context, some is far more common than certain. But I'd say aspects is just plain wrong...

The relevant meaning of aspect as used here is this OED definition...

aspect
One of the ways in which things may be looked at or contemplated, or in which they present themselves to the mind; a phase.

...which in the cited context is equivalent to perspective (the more common term today). Note that both of these terms normally take the preposition [looked at] from [some aspects / perspectives / viewpoints / angles]


Thank you! Very helpful.
